# how to resolve android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070187 type #0x4 is not valid

Tags: android

i m using below methods and i m getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070187 type #0x4 is not valid.
Code:

```
float pageMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.pageMargin);
        float pageOffset = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset);

 <dimen name="pageMargin">20</dimen>
    <dimen name="offset">30</dimen>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes this happens when installing an application to a device or emulator after adding new resources. Try uninstalling the app first.

Comment: res-> values -> dimen

Comment: it's because `int` is not `dimen` [dimension has to have unit](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension)

Comment: uninstalling also same issue

Comment: Uninstalling the app and then cleaning and rebuilding the solution before redeploying helped me with a similar error that came up after changing the build from Release to Debug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure the dimensions have a defined unit:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension

In your case do as next. Notice the **dp** postfix after each value:

```
<dimen name="pageMargin">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="offset">30dp</dimen>
```